# How to prevent a chrome extension from running on chrome:// urls

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension throws an error if I try to open the popup.html on chrome:// urls.

I have set the callback function to prevent this:

```
/ Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after the popout has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
  // catching injecting into chrome:// pages error
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'js/payload.js'
  }, ()=>{
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("injecting error");
    }
    });;
});
```

The error is however still showing up. Is there any way of permitting `"chrome://*/"` in my manifest file?

Comment: Remove console.log but leave the `if` line and there'll be no error. Also there's no need for chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() - where did you get that? If it's on StackOverflow, I'd like to remove this wrong info as I see it too often.

Comment: @wOxxOm working perfectly, feel free to make an answer and please include why the console.log() was a problem, I am curious

Comment: console.log writes "injecting error" to the console so when you remove console.log nothing is written to the console - provided you still access chrome.runtime.lastError.